Characteristics curves of a PDE.
The characteristics curves of the equation $$x^2u_{xx}- y^2u_{yy} = x^2y^2 +x; x>0, u=(x,y)$$ are
$(a)$ Rectangular hyperbola
$(b)$ Parabola
$(c)$ Circle
$(d)$ Straight line.
I tried as $$R= x^2, S= 0, T= -y^2.$$ Characteristic roots are given as $$ \lambda =\pm \frac{y}{x}$$ and corresponding characteristics curves are solutions of the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}= \pm\frac{y}{x}.$$ But solutions of these equations are $xy=c$ and $y=cx$ which are both hyperbolic and straight lines. There is single correct option. Which option is correct one? Thank you.

Remember what characteristic curves are for: reparametrizing a PDE so it becomes a family of ODEs. If you reparametrize using the options you've worked out, which option gives you this?

@rake if possible give detailed solutions
